# How can I connect to Azure by python script?

Tags: python-3.x, azure

there are a way to connect in my azure account to do some operation by python script?
For example, scale-out of my application service plan?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this question is very broad, as it's just a general requirement. I'd suggest starting by looking at the Azure SDK for Python, to see all of the operations you can do. Then, when you're stuck on a specific issue, post a follow-up question.

Comment: Hi,if you think my answer helps you, could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> For example, scale-out of my application service plan?

You could refer to the [Update App Service Plan sdk code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/fb5185eb3f0f3eb98fde8bcd32ae45d06faafba2/azure-mgmt-web/azure/mgmt/web/operations/app_service_plans_operations.py#L298) in the [azure-mgmt-web](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/azure-mgmt-web) python sdk.

Or please see the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/createorupdate) to implement the similar requirements.